# Importing pygame raises an ImportError

Tags: python, pygame

I've been using pygame and python for a while now, and never has pygame ever raised this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dodgeball.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Library not loaded: 
@executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
Reason: unsafe use of @executable_path in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so with restricted binary
```

I've been installing heaps of python packages like pip, Distribute, py2app and more so could some of those things be "breaking" pygame?

Comment: You need to install SDL: https://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: I'm pretty sure I installed SDL.

Answer (score 0):

You may have 2 SDL libraries installed, find all occurrences of sdl and reinstall just one, or remove 1 and leave the other.

Comment: Where do I find the SDL libraries?

Comment: what OS are you using? if it is linux try  /usr/local/lib/ and /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

Comment: I found a SDL.framework in SDL.framework in Frameworks in Library? Does that count as a duplicate?

Comment: And I'm using Mac El Capital (10.11)